# Python Selenium: How to optimise a button selection & submitting process?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I made a bot to play a browser game for me. The bot clicks buttons presented on a web page to continue with a story line. And I require a help with optimising the button selection, checking & submitting process.

#### **How can I make a Python Selenium script to get all the buttons on the page and select a specific one from the available ones.**

The bot right now works as follows:

```py
x = 0

while x < 99999:

    if x < 99999:
        try:
            browser.get('https://censoredgame.com/city/adventure/decision/7')
            time.sleep(0.4)
            browser.get('https://censoredgame.com/city/adventure/')
            x = x + 1
        except:
            pass

        try:
            browser.get('https://censoredgame.com/city/adventure/decision/25')
            time.sleep(0.4)
            browser.get('https://censoredgame.com/city/adventure/')
            x = x + 1
        except:
            pass
```

```html
<a class="btn" title="Вземете решение!" href="/city/adventure/decision/29">Подслушайте</a>
<!-- This is how a button looks, I cant use NAME,ID,CLASS -->
```

It is pretty simple:

`/city/adventure/decision/7` = *Some button*, `/city/adventure/decision/25` = *Other button*.

The way my bot works is it tries to press a button by entering a link in the browser bar and it does this very slow because it checks 15 buttons on the page.
Could you please advise me on how I could improve this process?

Comment: Can you clarify your issue. Is it trying to interact with the webpage or simply loading URLs?

Comment: @DMart I want to make the bot interact with the page by clicking specific buttons, but I don't know how to do it , so I load urls.

Comment: No where on the script are you clicking buttons, so if it is slow then it is because you are loading urls and not clicking buttons. Where are you clicking buttons? And what is the crieria for choosing which one to click

Comment: @EdekiOkoh The buttons are on the web page, the criteria is only  for the button to exist.

Comment: Are all the buttons on the same page, or do you get new buttons on each page view?

Comment: @Greg Burghardt buttons have the same img but their text changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm so happy to tell you I found my way to approach the problem.
I'm sorry for everyone who didn't understand my problem and wanted to help.
I fixed my code and now its really fast. Here is a little example:

```py
x = 0
while x < 1000:
    try:
        browser.find_element_by_link_text('Пълна атака').click()
        browser.find_element_by_link_text('Продължи').click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass

    try:
        browser.find_element_by_link_text('Изправете се срещу врага').click()
        browser.find_element_by_link_text('Продължи').click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
```

etc
I feel really stupid right now. The answer was so easy but I didn't get in right away.
First time i tried to find element by link text I forgot to set except NoSuchElementException and i got problems...
Thank you all for help!

Answer (score 0):

Nikolay, I'm rly want to help you, but I didn't get how you gonna click on the button - " by entering a link in the browser bar"? Anyway, you need to open your page, then find all elements by Xpath `driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='btn' and @title='Вземете решение!']")`. Collect all those elements in WebElements list, then do foreach loop(I'm writing code on Java and C#, so u have to do it yourself). This loop gonna be clicking on each "Подслушайте" button on the page. If you have any questions let me know.